# Typescript Function Declaration, style difference

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, method-declaration

I started to use Typescript and i don't get what differences in these method declarations are:

```
onSave(){ /*method body*/ }
public onSave = () => { /*method body*/ }
```

Also, What I am supposed to search on Google or StackOverflow to find more about this topic?

Thank you,

(Sorry for the long post :D)

Comment: see this [link](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html) or [this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/arrow/)

Comment: Maybe this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433652/different-ways-to-define-a-method-in-typescript/47434165#47434165

Comment: Thank you all for the support! I marked my question as duplicate. I apologize, but i didn't know what to look for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to **regular functions** and **arrow function**, they're explained in detail in TypeScript docs:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

The general difference between a regular function and arrow function is that regular function operates within it's own scope (this) while arrow function remains in the scope of the parent.

Comment: Sorry but this is not quite correct. The question asks about method syntax vs property syntax.

Comment: And what exactly is not correct in my answer ? Also I am pretty sure he's asking about the difference in function declaration ...

Comment: The link you passed in the comment has exactly the same answer as mine ... you failed to make your point.

Comment: Thank you mate. I was asking about function declaration as well @AluanHaddad.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović you're right, I overlooked that. Sorry: +1